# AWSのEC2上のcronでMiniMagick(ImageMagick)のPathを通したいです

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aws, amazon-ec2, cron, imagemagick

AWSのEC2上のcronでMiniMagick(ImageMagick)のPathを通したいです

cronで実行したいスクリプトでmini_magickを使用しています。
これが原因なのか実行すると以下失敗するログが吐かれます。

cronでPATH通す必要があると認識していますが、通し方がわかっていません。
またmini_magickのインストール先を設定すればよいのでしょうか。
（mini_magickはgemでインストール済みです）
インストール先の調べ方など知識が不十分です。
ご教示いただけないでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。

```
バリデーションに失敗しました: Imagetranslation missing: ja.erors.messages.mini_magick_processing_error
```

Comment: エラーメッセージから察するに、MiniMagick のコマンド(おそらく convert コマンド)は実行されていて、変換対象の画像ファイルが存在しないか(ファイルパスを間違えているなど)、MiniMagick が対応していない形式の画像ではないかと。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ローカル環境でも確認してみましたが、読み込む画像は特に問題なく処理が完了しています。ですのでサーバーの問題と思いこのご質問に至りました。サーバー上でもimagemagickインストールが必要だとしたら、どのようにするのが良いかよくわかっていません・・

Comment: 質問にはエラーメッセージだけでなく、関連するコードなども含めた方が回答のヒントになるかもしれません。動作する (ローカル) 環境があるのなら、EC2 環境との違いは何なのかを手掛かりに調べてみるのも一つの方法かと。

Comment: ありがとうございます。質問自体が内容不足で不適切でしたので
修正しました。ごめんなさい

Answer (score 0):

こちらを参考にImageMagicのPATHを追加することで解決できました。
ありがとうございます。
https://qiita.com/piggydev/items/b13c0f0cf0ba67761f08
https://qiita.com/positrium/items/a2de9af6c5b4d06b504e